# How to stop setInterval() cycle with discord command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I write my own bot for Discord server. So, I want to create command, which can change your nickname every 3 seconds (yeah, it's so useless, but interesting :3). So, I wrote programm for starting, but I don't know how to stop this machine without crash. I want to do seperate argument "stop", which will stop cylce and restore old nickname. How can I do it in one script? Command in Discord looks like ***?nicks start*** and ***?nicks stop***.
I have a handler script, which checks command coincidences in config.json and passes arguments and message object from the command. So, my goal is starting and stopping functions in one script. Cylce is reimplemented by setInterval() and I have to stop it. I hope somebody will understand what I want...)
P. S. Sorry for my English :3

```js
'use strict';
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require('../config.json');
const writeLogs = require('../writeLogs.js'); 
const fs = require('fs');

function creepingLine(msg, args) {
    const user = msg.guild.member(msg.author) 
    const firstNickname = user.nickname; // backup for stopping
    if (args[0] === "старт") {
        let nicks = args.slice(1);
        let pointer = 0;
        function changeNick() {
            user.setNickname(nicks[pointer]);
            if (pointer === nicks.length - 1) {
                pointer = 0;
            }
            else pointer++; 
        }
        let timer = setInterval(changeNick, 3000);
    }
}

module.exports = creepingLine;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an object to keep references for the intervals like so:

```
...
const intervals = {};

function creepingLine(msg, args) {
    ...
        intervals[msg.author] = setInterval(changeNick, 3000);
    }
}
```

Then use it to stop the interval

```
function stopInterval(author) {
    clearInterval(intervals[author]);
}
```